# Unable to auto Merge Git Pull request :: No Conflict

Tags: git, github, merge, conflict, git-merge

My team and I are experience some issues using github enterprise and I was hoping someone out there might have experience this problem.

Our development workflow is straight forward, Developer creates a feature branch off of develop, makes changes and submits a pull request back into develop. The code is reviews and merged into develop. We have been working this way for a couple of years, but recently several of our developers started experiencing an issue where pull request from about 5 of our developers says it cannot be auto merged. So thinking the cause is a merge conflict I run through the merge via command line and it merges cleanly with no merge conflicts.

I went through all the pull request that won't auto merge and they all merged successfully via command line.

Since it wasn't happening to everyone I assumed it was the developers local code base acting up. I had the devs trash their local and clone the repo. I had each dev one at a time make a small change and submit a pull request. They all would not auto merge again.

I am hoping someone out there has experience this problem and know how to resolve.

Thanks in advance and let me know if you need any more info.

Gregg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick workaround for this issue is to have your users browse to `http(s)://[hostname]/settings/emails` and make sure they have an email address that is marked as the primary.

Once I had all the develops perform the above task all of there pull requests had the option auto merge.

I spoke with Github about this bug and they said it's resolve in the current release is 11.10.326 https://enterprise.github.com/releases/11.10.326.